# Notificações param de aparecer e dá erro no console

Tags: android

Estava a receber cerca 7 notificações mal o utilizador logava  que eram colocadas por um alarme e enviadas para um alarme receiver onde cria a notificação cada uma com o seu id.

Executei novamente a app com o mesmo código (exatamente igual) e aparece este erro sempre  que tento criar as notificações em massa no login. Em outras partes do código funciona normalmente.

```
Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder'
```

Alguém sabe como resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Fala Tiago,

É melhor você postar o código aqui, da pra entender onde você possivelmente está errando, mas tente fazer o seguinte:

Troque:

```
Notification.Builder mbuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
```

Por:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

Abraços.